# Position one UIlabel under another UILabel (top label has varying height)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have two UILabels inside of a XIB, and I want to position one label underneath of another label. That said, the top label's height (descriptionLabel) varies. Does anyone know how I can go about doing this? I feel like I've tried everything.

Here is the code for my Labels so far; I want to position my second label (bodyLabel) about 25 pixels below descriptionLabel (regardless of how long descriptionLabel is):

```
  CGRect frame = descriptionLabel.frame;
            frame.origin.y=400;//pass the cordinate which you want
            frame.origin.x= 12;//pass the cordinate which you want
            descriptionLabel.frame= frame;

  CGRect frame2 = bodyLabel.frame;
            bodyLabel.frame= frame;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have two `UILabel`s. Say, `firstLabel` and `secondLabel`. Suppose you have set the first frame like so:

`firstLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,50,50);`

If your first frame dynamically changes its height, and if want your secondLabel to be always under the first, you can set the `y` coordinate of the `secondLabel` in such a way it is always under it. The code for it can be something like:

`secondLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0,firstLabel.frame.size.height,50,50);`

Using this, the `y` position of the `secondLabel` is dynamic and is dependent on the `firstLabel`'s height.

In your case, the position of the `bodyLabel` can be :

```
CGRect bodyLabelFrame = CGRectMake(0,descriptionLabel.frame.size.height,50,50);
bodyLabel.frame = bodyLabelFrame;
```

Comment: Okay, so here's my problem. When I use that code, for some reason, it positions both labels at the top of my ViewController. I can't seem to set the position of my first label from the top of the controller (e.g. 100px from the top)?

Comment: Try this one, `descriptionLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0,100,50,50);`

Comment: Okay so this works perfectly:   descriptionLabel.frame = CGRectMake(13,400,300,descriptionLabel.frame.size.height); So now how do I position bodyLabel below that? :-) P.S. - Thank you!

Comment: Is the `bodyLabel` being placed wherever you want too? That was the initial problem, right?
Now, you have to set the `bodyLabel`'s frame as:
`bodyLabel.frame = CGRectMake(13,descriptionLabel.frame.size.height+400,300,bodyLabel.frame.size.height);`

Comment: I need bodyLabel to appear underneath of descriptionLabel. For some reason that part isn't working (I position descriptionLabel fine, but bodyLabel doesn't seem to want to move underneath of it). Using this line: secondLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0,firstLabel.frame.size.height,50,50); makes bodyLabel disappear all together.

Comment: Also really strange: Even after implementing descriptionLabel.frame = CGRectMake(13,400,300,descriptionLabel.frame.size.height); , my label is in a different position on various screens?

Comment: Various screens? What are various screens?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60104/discussion-between-avismara-and-brittany).

Answer (score 1):

do this in `viewDidLayoutSubviews;`

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    /* set label1's frame first */

    CGRect newFrame = _label2.frame;
    newFrame.origin.y = CGRectGetMaxY(_label1.frame)+25;
    _label2.frame = newFrame;
}
```

`CGRectGetMaxY` takes the frame's origin into account when returning a value. keep in mind that frames are not yet set for views if you're doing things in `loadView` or `viewDidLoad`, this could be why things keep ending up with a 0 origin - they are still 0 at that time.

Comment: This doesn't account for the text changing in the first label though — it could have to be resized to a new height.

Comment: if the label needs to get resized to a new height, presumably that will trigger the controller to layoutSubviews again. my solution does handle that case.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using autolayout? Using autolayout, this is how I might do this if the superview for the labels was `superView`:

```
// This is necessary to use autolayout
descriptionLabel.translatesAutoResizingMasksIntoConstraints = NO;
bodyLabel.translatesAutoResizingMasksIntoConstraints = NO;

NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(descriptionLabel, bodyLabel);

// this will pin the top of bodyLabel to the bottom of the descriptionLabel with a gap of 25px
[superView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[descriptionLabel]-25-[bodyLabel]" options:nil metrics:nil views:views]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do it in code. I use auto-layout.

First, create two private NSLayoutContstraint variables for your two labels — you'll use these to adjust your label height when you set the text.

```
@interface CustomView ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSLayoutConstraint *firstLabelHeightCn;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSLayoutConstraint *secondLabelHeightCn;
@end
```

Second, define the first labels X, Y, and width — the height will be set depending on the text you set in it.

```
NSLayoutConstraint *cnX;
NSLayoutConstraint *cnY;
NSLayoutConstraint *cnWidth;

// first label
_firstLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
_firstLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
_firstLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
_firstLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[self addSubview:_firstLabel];

cnX = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_firstLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft multiplier:1.0 constant:H_MARGIN];
cnY = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_firstLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0 constant:V_MARGIN];
cnWidth = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_firstLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight multiplier:1.0 constant:-H_MARGIN];
_firstLabelHeightCn = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_firstLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:0 constant:0];
[self addConstraints:@[ cnX, cnY, cnWidth, _firstLabelHeightCn ]];
```

Third, define the second labels X, Y, and width off the first labels properties. For the Y position you'll want to set the second labels TOP to the first labels BOTTOM (+ any margin).

```
// second label
_secondLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
_secondLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
_secondLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
_secondLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[self addSubview:_secondLabel];

cnX = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_secondLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:_firstLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft multiplier:1.0 constant:0];
cnY = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_secondLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:_firstLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0 constant:V_MARGIN];
cnWidth = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_secondLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:_firstLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight multiplier:1.0 constant:0];
_secondLabelHeightCn = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_secondLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:0 constant:0];
[self addConstraints:@[ cnX, cnY, cnWidth, _secondLabelHeightCn ]];
```

Finally, create two methods to set the text for your two labels. These methods will take the incoming text, calculate the height, adjust your layout constraint constants, and then set the actual text in the label. **Since you're using auto-layout once you change the text/height of the first label, the second label will automatically adjust.**

```
- (void)setFirstText:(NSString *)firstText
{
    _firstText = firstText;

    if (_firstText.length) {
        _firstLabelHeightCn.constant = [CustomView textHeight:_firstText width:self.bounds.size.width font:_firstLabel.font];
        _firstLabel.text = _firstText;
    } else {
        _firstLabelHeightCn.constant = 0;
        _firstLabel.text = nil;
    }
}

- (void)setSecondText:(NSString *)secondText
{
    _secondText = secondText;

    if (_secondText.length) {
        _secondLabelHeightCn.constant = [CustomView textHeight:_secondText width:self.bounds.size.width font:_secondLabel.font];
        _secondLabel.text = _secondText;
    } else {
        _secondLabelHeightCn.constant = 0;
        _secondLabel.text = nil;
    }
}
```

**Here is a real-life example:**

ContextView.h
https://gist.githubusercontent.com/rosem/4fc7f9ed80c114ba45a0/raw/05f46c0340e1682823d6bbeb95f8b084ba4449d5/gistfile1.mm

ContextView.m
https://gist.githubusercontent.com/rosem/6d768776991569496ab6/raw/76ce4f47b3f86555ee4755e7d52d12511adcec27/gistfile1.m

Comment: The margin, and public labels in the .h might not be needed be you. Ideally you would just have the setText methods exposed and not the labels. However, I needed to expose them externally for alignment/spacing in the parent view.